# GetManifestResourceStream and xDoc.Save can work together?

Tags: c#, xml, file, xml-parsing

Any thoughts on why the following code causes the app to crash?

The application is collected and signed, launched on a real phone.

```
var assembly = IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(typeof(ListData)).Assembly;
        Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("App14.Data.xml");

        XElement xDoc = XElement.Load(stream);
        xDoc.Element("students").Add(
        new XElement("mainStudent",
                    new XAttribute("type", "Editor"),
                    new XElement("student", "new student")));
        xDoc.Save(stream);
```

Comment: I don't think you can modify the data embedded in the application. At least for me the `CanWrite` property of such a stream is `false`.

Comment: what should I do? I need to delete and add data.

Comment: You should store the data in an appropriate location. I don't know how this works on phones, but on desktops it would be in `%AppData%`, `%LocalAppData%` or `%ProgramData%`, depending on the use case, or using isolated storage.